# How to display two different list in view page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am New to ASP MVC ,I Having Two list in action method First list contains task details and second list contains Employee ids i want to send both list to the view page with paging.My Problem is i am not able to send both list to view

```
public ActionResult DisplayProjectTask(string projectId, int? page)
{            
    List<Task> projectTasksList =bHelper.GetProjectTaskList(projectId);
    List<string> empIds = dbHelper.GetTaskEmployeesId(projectId);           
    return View(projectTasksList.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
}
```

Comment: Consider making a [strongly typed view](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) which has fields for both lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view model to hold them:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public FooViewModel()
    {
       Tasks = new List<Task>();
       EmpIds = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmpIds { get; set; }
}
```

Populate them from your controller and return the model:

```
public ActionResult DisplayProjectTask(string projectId, int? page)
{    
    var model = new FooViewModel();
    model.Tasks = dbHelper.GetProjectTaskList(projectId).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
    model.EmpIds = dbHelper.GetTaskEmployeesId(projectId);           
    return View(model);
}
```

Then add this to your view:

```
@model FooViewModel

@foreach(var task in Model.Tasks)
{
   @* Replace with your properties in the Task object *@
   @task.ProperyName
}

@foreach(var empId in Model.EmpIds)
{
   @empId
}
```

Comment: it will fall on View if `dbHelper` returns `null` sometimes

Comment: @teovankot Good point, updated view model to prevent that. It's difficult to tell without seeing what those methods return though. I would usually return an empty list rather than null.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Model for example:

```
public class MyTwoListsModel
{
    public List<Cars> ListName1;
    public List<Animals> ListName2;

    public MyTwoLists(List<Cars> list1, List<Animals> list2)
    {   
        this.ListName1 = list1;
        this.ListName2 = list2;
    }
}
```

And then create in a ViewController instance of it and the pass it to the View. If you have some question - ask